# How do I take the Fourier transform of $f(x)\frac{d\,f(x)}{dx}\frac{d\,g(x)}{dx}$?

Tags: fourier-transform

I am trying to solve a PDE using Fourier transformation similar to how [the telegraph equation might be solved.](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m267/pdeft.pdf) This is done by Fourier transforming each term. It happens that one of the terms is given by

$$f(x)\frac{d\,f(x)}{dx}\frac{d\,g(x)}{dx}.$$

I am trying to take the Fourier transform of this, which would boil down to the integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\frac{d\,f(x)}{dx}\frac{d\,g(x)}{dx} e^{-ikx} dx.$$

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I know the general property

$$\text{FT}[f^{(n)}(x)]=(ik)^n\,\hat{f}(k)$$

for a derivative but I have never encountered a Fourier transform that is a product of several functions and derivatives. Does anyone know a trick, theorem or hint that could point me in the right direction? Or would this be very difficult to simplify? I have limited experience with the Fourier transformation and I am looking to learn.

Comment: Your equation isn't linear, so don't expect too much from the Fourier transform...